# Installing PyQt4 on Windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt4

I have tried installing the binary from lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyqt4 for python 3.5 and 3.6 both. Still it is not working. Now it throws DLL error. How to fix it?

`builtins.ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick look inside the .whi for Python 3.6 with [dependency walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) suggests that the package requires `msvcp140.dll` and `vcruntime140.dll` which are part of the [Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145)